# como fechar uma popup com javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom galera montei uma função para abrir um popup, e preciso colocar um link dentro da popup para ela ser fechada. Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Meu código para abrir a pop-up

```
function popup(URL) {
var width = 1024;
var height = 700;
var left = 30;
var top = 50;
window.open(URL, 'janela', 'width=' + width + ', height=' + height + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left + ', scrollbars=yes, status=no, toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, menubar=no, resizable=no, fullscreen=no');
```

}

Chamo o link assim:

```
<a onclick="javascript:popup('janela.html')">Link</a>
```

Dentro do arquivo janela.html preciso colocar um link para fechar a pop-up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

com este código você pode fechar:

```
<a href='#' onclick='window.close()'>Fechar modal</a>
```